# Qt crashes when I try to use OpenNI2 library

Tags: c++, qt, openni

I'm trying to use the OpenNI library in a Qt C++ application. When I call anything from the OpenNI library and compile and run I get "The program has unexpectedly finished." instantly.. No error messages no nothing..

What I know:

- It's the OpenNI library that causes this.
- The include path and lib path in the .PRO file are set correctly.
- I'm also using OpenCV and NiTE which I can access as expected.

Thank you in advance for the help :)

UPDATE:

I solved the problem, it wasn't directly related with the openNI library. I had the environment variables pointing to the 64bit library when I was building my application with a 32bit compiler.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What happens when you debug it? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: completly empty... I get no information at all about what is causing it..."Debugging starts
Debugging has finished" I think it might be some incompatibility that I'm not understanding.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially without the additional libraries?

Comment: I only have a main that call OpenNI's getVersion and it crashes. The other libraries was just a test to see if my library paths were set right. The main thing is that one line of code from the OpenNI library crashes when I run it

Comment: When you find an answer, do not edit a remark into your question, but post a complete and self contained answer *as an answer* (which you then may accept).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe OpenNI can not open device.

Try to copy folder OpenNI2 from `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenNI2\Redist`  and paste it to your release/debug folder.

Comment: I forgot to update the question. I solved it some while ago. Thank you though for the awnser.